FLTK insert function now needs only 2 arguments instead of 3?
I had a small application in Rust language using FLTK. It was created and worked will around 1.5 years back. Now I reinstalled Rust and tried to build application from same source code. I am getting  error that insert function of grid objects now need only 2 arguments  and  not 3 (object, x, y) as before.
error[E0061]: this method takes 2 arguments but 3 arguments were supplied
   --> src/main.rs:593:14
    |
593 |         grid.insert(&mut self.newbtn, x..x+2, y); x+=3; 
    |              ^^^^^^                           - unexpected argument #3 of type `usize`
    |
note: expected `i32`, found `Range<i32>`
   --> src/main.rs:593:39
    |
593 |         grid.insert(&mut self.newbtn, x..x+2, y); x+=3; 
    |                                       ^^^^^^
    = note: expected type `i32`
             found struct `std::ops::Range<i32>`
note: method defined here
   --> /home/iuser/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/fltk-1.4.34/src/prelude.rs:651:8
    |
651 |     fn insert<W: WidgetExt>(&mut self, widget: &W, index: i32)
    |        ^^^^^^
help: remove the extra argument

Why this change in fltk-grid package? How can this error be  resolved? The single value now needed is  for x or y? What is the function to insert at (x,y) position?

Did you preserve the original Cargo.lock? Can you provide your original Cargo.toml dependencies? Or did you recreate them?

I think you create with pos, insert is into a group index

Regardless of how you got into this state, if you're using the latest version of fltk-grid it looks like you want .set_widget now.

All 3 comments above are very useful. Thanks. @kmdreko : The set_widget works very well instead of older insert. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it and it will be better visible to other users as well.
